# What is the total number of threads running in the following java code for executing splash screen?

Tags: multithreading

The following code executes the splash screen in a software application. An object of class Loading Window is made on the the main class to call the constructor. What is the count of total threads used in the following code :

```
public LoadingWindow() {
     setUndecorated(true);
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/snakegame/icons/splash.png"));
    imageLabel.setIcon(image);
    setLayout(null);
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i=0;
            while(i <= 100){
                progressBar.setValue(i);
                try {
                    sleep(95);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                i=i+5;
            }
        }
    }
    ).start();
        startProgress();
}
```

Comment: There is the UI Thread and you are explicitly creating another one. In debugging tools you may see additional ones for GC or Threads created elsewhere, though.

Comment: You never set `t` by the way. What's it for?

Comment: BTW if `progressBar` is, what it seems to be (a UI component) you can't set its value in a  thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: @derpirscher I guess that's where this is going ... x-y

Comment: Re, `progressBar.setValue(i)`, Read about [`javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)). It's how a background thread (e.g., your `while` loop) can submit a task (i.e., a `Runnable`) that the UI thread will perform at the next opportunity.